# How do you get react-select's AsyncSelect component to retain its value after selection?

Tags: react-select

I have an AsyncSelect component working perfectly *except* that, after selecting something, the control doesn't retain its value.  It just goes back to saying "Select..."

Just in case that's not clear, my AsyncSelect queries MS Graph to get back a list of users based on what you type into the box.  It does this as expected.  If I type in "Ed" it brings back all the people with "Ed" in their name, etc., and displays them in a dropdown.  When I pick one, my handler function in onChange fires, and everything is fabulous.  The only problem is that as soon as I pick someone, the control goes back to saying "Select..." when I'm thinking it ought to retain the value of the person I selected.

The example given here doesn't appear to do anything special, and the value of the color you select is retained in the box.  https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/codesandboxer-example-w84rny?module=%2Fexample.tsx